# calculating the depth of polymorphic bst object recursively

Tags: java, recursion, polymorphism, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to calculate the depth of a key in a polymorphic bst (instead of null objects empty objects are denoted by EmptyTrees) and I'm not sure how to implement the actual code.

```
private int calcDepth(K keyIn, int level){ 
 if (this.key.compareTo(keyIn) == 0) return level; 

  if (this.key.compareTo(keyIn) < 0){ 
  return left.calcDepth(keyIn, level+1); 
  }

  if (this.key.compareTo(keyIn) > 0){ 
  return right.calcDepth(keyIn, level+1); 
  }

  return -1; 
}
```

I'm very new to java so forgive the basic and or confused nature of the question

So my question is, how do i calculate the depth of a key in my bst?

Comment: What is the concrete question here?

Comment: How would i calculate the depth of a key in my bst

Comment: whats wrong with what u have now?

Comment: in your class definition, are the generic types K and V there?

Comment: yes they are there, @ChrisGong

Comment: Also, is this method in class `Tree` instead of `NonEmptyTree`?

Comment: this method is in class NonEmptyTree...I can post the constructor and class details?

Comment: yes that would be helpful

Comment: just added @ChrisGong

Comment: how are you calling the method?

Comment: @ChrisGong i've added it

Comment: Can you also include the header for `NonEmptyTree`? Make sure the generics are included in that as well

Comment: @ChrisGong i've done so

Comment: I posted an answer, please tell me if my suggestions don't work but i hope u at least understand the issue now

Comment: Your answer definately helped I couldn't wrap my mind around the problem at first but now I have a good grasp...if we couldn't explicitly check if the tree was empty like you suggest in solution 2 how would you about it?

Comment: Try moving the `depthKey` and `calcDepth` methods to the `Tree` class.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is with these two lines of code inside your `calcDepth` method,

```
return left.calcDepth(keyIn, level+1);
```

and

```
return right.calcDepth(keyIn, level+1);
```

You can only call `calcDepth` on objects that have the `calcDepth` method. However, because `calcDepth` is only defined in `NonEmptyTree`, what happens when you reach the end of a branch and hit a `EmptyTree`? This is where you'll receive an error because `EmptyTree` does not have this method. And this took me a while to realize because the error didn't state this but since it's a subclass of `Tree<K,V>`, it's going to directly say the method doesn't exist in the superclass. So I have two suggestions, either

1. Put the `calcDepth` method in your superclass `Tree` so that both subclasses have access to it

or

2. Before doing a recursive call, first check if the `left` or `right` is an `EmptyTree`. If it is, then return `level+1` in that case (assuming you count the empty nodes as an extra level, if not then just return `level`).